# What to do with ground wire in light fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m installing a light fixture that has a white wire, a black wire, and a ground wire.

The ceiling where the new light fixture goes only has a white wire and a black wire (hot). It doesn’t have a ground wire.

What can I do with the ground wire from the light fixture so that everything’s grounded?

These are the cables connected to the switch: there are only two black wires and both are hot:
[image]

These are the cables coming from the ceiling. There’s only a black wire and a white wire (already connected to the light fixture):
[image]

Comment: "The outlet where I’ll be installing the light fixture" do you mean "electrical box"? If so is it plastic or metal.

Comment: Sorry. That meant the wires coming out of the ceiling.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the electrical box in question please?

Comment: @rbhat "*wires coming out of the ceiling.*"   Does not provide any useful info. Are the wires in a box, what kind of box, no box. **More info is needed**

Comment: Peel that electrical tape off of there and use proper wire nuts. The adhesive on that tape _will_ dry out and the tape will fall off. That's why this doesn't meet code.

Comment: Can you post a photo that looks squarely into the back of the light fixture box, with the crossbar removed, please?

Comment: Do you mean the ceiling and the wires coming from the ceiling?

Comment: @rbhat -- the box in the ceiling, and the metal plate sitting across the box in the ceiling

Answer (score 1):

If it's a metal box with EMT, then the box is probably grounded and you could attach the ground from the light to a 10-32 ground screw into the box. If it old style NM cable with no ground, then just tuck the ground wire into the box away from the other wires. You can fold it and tape with electrical tape if it helps you sleep at night. There is no way then to ground your fixture.

Comment: I’ve included pictures.

Comment: It looks like there are only two black wire in the switch box  so it's conduit and should be grounded. If you have a electric meter read between black and metal box at the ceiling. Look for about 120V. If you get it, the box is grounded. Be careful taking readings as black will be hot with switch on. Remember to turn off the breaker after taking any readings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ceiling box is metal the switch box definitely is metal connecting the ground wire to the box or the cross brace is about all you can do it is possible your boxes are grounded if not you don’t have a ground I find many stucco homes built prior to 3 wire are grounded through the mesh so connecting to the box may provide a ground but not guaranteed. If you turn the switch off one conductor will be the switched and the other will be the hot.